# GTK3 Adjustment Issue

Tags: c, gtk, adjustment

I have come across an issue using adjustments for spin buttons. What I want to do is in response to a radio button toggle signal, I want to change the adjustment associated with a spin button. So, the handler for the spin button toggle signal gets the spin button passed to it. The adjustments themselves are globals, so no need to pass them. Example code is attached. If I don't re-initialize the adjustments (the commented code) in the handler, I get all warnings/errors when the handler runs and tries to adjust the the spin button values. BTW, I am running this code on an Rpi3B+. Clicking radio button "Pgm by DAC Code" works - it changes the spin button values as requested. But when the "Pgm by Voltage" radio button is clicked, the pgm misbehaves as shown in the console window output shown below here. Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

```
(adjustment_issue:4441): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref_sink: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(adjustment_issue:4441): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer

(adjustment_issue:4441): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(adjustment_issue:4441): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer

(adjustment_issue:4441): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(adjustment_issue:4441): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_adjustment_get_step_increment: assertion 'GTK_IS_ADJUSTMENT (adjustment)' failed

(adjustment_issue:4441): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_spin_button_value_changed: assertion 'GTK_IS_ADJUSTMENT (adjustment)' failed
```

```
/*
 * adjustment_issue.c.c
 * 
 */

#include <math.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *sblblVdc;
    GtkWidget *sbVdc;
} dcvWidgets_t;

// structure to hold the data for adjustments
typedef struct {
    double initVal;
    double minVal;
    double maxVal;
    double stepVal;
} adj_t;

adj_t vdcLimits;
adj_t dacCodeLimits;

GtkAdjustment *adjSbVoltLimits;
GtkAdjustment *adjSbCodeLimits;

static void dcPgmModeChanged(GtkToggleButton *btn, dcvWidgets_t *dcvWid)
{
    // BUG WORKAROUND: Re-initialize the adjustments.
    // When the Pgm by Code rb is clicked, all is well.
    // But when the Pgm by Voltage is clicked, the sbVoltLimits adjustment
    // appears to point to nothing and program displays lots of errors in
    // terminal window.

    if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(btn)) {
/*
        adjSbVoltLimits = gtk_adjustment_new(
            vdcLimits.initVal, vdcLimits.minVal, vdcLimits.maxVal,
            vdcLimits.stepVal, 0, 0);
*/

        // modify the spin button to show voltage range
        gtk_spin_button_configure(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(dcvWid->sbVdc),
                                    adjSbVoltLimits, 0, 3);
    }
    else {
/*
        adjSbCodeLimits = gtk_adjustment_new(
            dacCodeLimits.initVal, dacCodeLimits.minVal, dacCodeLimits.maxVal,
            dacCodeLimits.stepVal, 0, 0);
*/

        // modify the spin button to show DAC code range
        gtk_spin_button_configure(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(dcvWid->sbVdc),
                                    adjSbCodeLimits, 0, 0);
    }
}

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
    dcvWidgets_t *dcvWidgets = g_slice_new(dcvWidgets_t);

  window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK Adjustment Issue");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, -1);

  GtkWidget *hbx = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 10);

    vdcLimits.initVal = 2.5;
  vdcLimits.minVal = 0.0;
    vdcLimits.maxVal = 4.999;
    vdcLimits.stepVal = 0.001;

    adjSbVoltLimits = gtk_adjustment_new(
        vdcLimits.initVal, vdcLimits.minVal, vdcLimits.maxVal,
        vdcLimits.stepVal, 0, 0);

    dacCodeLimits.initVal = 2048;
    dacCodeLimits.minVal = 0;
    dacCodeLimits.maxVal = 4095;
    dacCodeLimits.stepVal = 1;

    adjSbCodeLimits = gtk_adjustment_new(
        dacCodeLimits.initVal, dacCodeLimits.minVal, dacCodeLimits.maxVal,
        dacCodeLimits.stepVal, 0, 0);

    dcvWidgets->sbVdc = gtk_spin_button_new(adjSbVoltLimits, 0, 3);
    gtk_entry_set_width_chars(GTK_ENTRY(dcvWidgets->sbVdc), 5);


    GtkWidget *rb1Mode = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(NULL, "Pgm. by voltage");
    GtkWidget *rb2Mode = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label_from_widget(
                            GTK_RADIO_BUTTON(rb1Mode), "Pgm. by DAC code");

    g_signal_connect(rb1Mode, "toggled",
                        G_CALLBACK(dcPgmModeChanged), dcvWidgets);

    GtkWidget *vboxMode = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vboxMode), rb1Mode, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vboxMode), rb2Mode, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbx), vboxMode, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbx), dcvWidgets->sbVdc, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),hbx);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);

  status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);

  g_object_unref(app);

  return status;
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing the adjustment properties into that structure? The gtk system does that for you. Work with gtk adjustment get functions and monitor its properties with “notify::property_name” signals.

Comment: I have a video on my YouTube channel about “notify” signal. https://youtu.be/ There are the exactly objects used in your code (spinButton and adjustment). You should check the GtkAdjustment playlist as well.